# Get Todays date and selected date in variable jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

**HTML:**

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var x = '';
 $('#calendar').datepicker({
     altField: '#datepicker_send',
     inline: true,
     firstDay: 1,
     showOtherMonths: true,
     dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
     onSelect: function (dateText) {
         $('#event-date').text(dateText)
     }
 });
```

On selecting variable stored in #event date, I am printing it as :

No Events on #event-date in span....

But when page loads for first time  i want to display : `No events on "Default Today's Date"` and when selected event-date should execute.

Please help me out in getting today's date stored in a variable so that i can show it when page loads.

Comment: You have shared incomplete HTML. Share full html.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer will be solve your problem

**Javascript**

```
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();
var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' +
    ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
    ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day;
 jQuery('#calendar').html('No events on ' + output);
```

**HTML**

```
<div><span id="calendar"></span></div>
```

Just we can show the today date as default date when page loads.

Comment: then what about selected date?? should i add the selected date script to the above code?